# Let checkboxes checked when submitted

Tags: html, css, forms, checkbox

**EDIT:**

How can we leave all the checkboxes checked after I submit and it comes back at the same page ?
When I submit, they are "reset" :/

So here is my form code:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="filtre_form">
<h1 class="text-center">Filtre</h1>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4 class="text-center">Colonne à Afficher</h4>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="model" name="checkbox[]" id="Modele"> Modèle
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="date_envoie" name="checkbox[]" id="Date"> Date envoi
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="distributeur" name="checkbox[]" id="Distributeur"> Distributeur
                        </label>
                    </li>
```

Comment: Yes, I read already that thread but he uses JS :/ Ok thanks anyway, I will do it another way or learn JS ><

Comment: It means you want to boil egg without having egg.

Comment: ok thanks i think its clear now :D

Comment: If you have a different question you should ask a new question not edit your current question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Not possible.** You cannot modify the `checked` property via HTML/CSS alone.

Comment: +1, for making it clear to OP. :)